# PHPExcel DataSeriesLabels not shown

Tags: php, phpexcel

PHPExcel is great and i really like the possibility to add a chart into a sheet. I played around a lot, but there is one thing i cannot get done. It's about showing the data series labels in the legend of the chart:
[image] 
I only get this result:
[image] (Please ignore the different style/colors)

Here i made a "small" example, did someone see what do wrong?

```
<?php
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
// header: download as xlxs file
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="data.xlsx"');
// create some sheet
$PHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$sheet = $PHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->fromArray([
  //    A           B       C          D
    ['Month'  ,'Data A', 'Data B', 'Data C'], // 1
    ['2015-08',   36.24,    65.23,    43.34], // 2
    ['2015-07',   54.15,    23.12,    28.53], // 3
    ['2015-06',   43.35,    56.43,     3.30], // 4
    ['2015-05',   62.56,    43.53,    32.63], // 5
    ['2015-04',   23.38,     3.34,     5.23]  // 6
]);

$dataSeriesLabels = [
    new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String','Data!$B$1',NULL,1), // B1
    new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String','Data!$C$1',NULL,1), // C1
    new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String','Data!$D$1',NULL,1)  // D1
];

$dataSeriesValues = [
    new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number','Data!$B$2:$B$6',NULL,5), // B2-B6
    new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number','Data!$C$2:$C$6',NULL,5), // C2-C6
    new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number','Data!$D$2:$D$6',NULL,5), // D2-D6
];

$xAxisLabels = [
    new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String','Data!$A$2:$A$6',NULL,5), // A2-A6
];

$dataSeries = new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_LINECHART,
    \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD,
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1),
    $dataSeriesLabels,
    $xAxisLabels,
    $dataSeriesValues
);

$pa = new \PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(null, array($dataSeries));
$legend = new \PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(\PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, NULL, false);

$chartTitle = new \PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Test');
$chart = new \PHPExcel_Chart('chart_'.uniqid(),$chartTitle,$legend,$pa,true,0,null,null);

$chart->setTopLeftPosition('A8');
$chart->setBottomRightPosition('K26');
$sheet->addChart($chart);

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($PHPExcel);
$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(true);
$objWriter->save("php://output");
```

As you can see the `$dataSeriesLabels` are set and attached to `$dataSeries`, which is part in `$pa` (PlotArea) of `$chart`. I do not really get why this is not working, i'm happy about any advise.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem on my own, so here the answer if someone have the same problem:

I always used `Data` in the "area strings" like `Data!$B$1`. Now i changed it to `Wooksheet`/ `Wooksheet!$B$1` because `Wooksheet` is the name of my sheet. Seems that this is required.